# Loopback can't update extension model without setting password

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

So i have the following a model which has the `User` model as `base` :

```
  "name": "Member",
  "base": "User",
```

Now when logged in as a `member` i attempt to `update` the additional information of the `member` `model`

However, since I am not passing the password I get the following:

```
The `Member` instance is not valid. Details: `password` can't be blank (value: undefined).
```

This is an issue since I am only interested in updating my own custom fields and not necessarily update the password.

Does anyone know how i can avoid this error?

Comment: set password as not required or pass dummy data in that field?

Comment: @sweaver2112 how can i get the built in models?

Comment: not sure, just a guess based on a google search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&q=%60password%60+can%27t+be+blank+%28value%3A+undefined%29

Comment: @sweaver2112 and by setting it to not required i am still updating that field

Answer (score 0):

So Inside the Member model, Just set the password property value to `false`.

Example:

```
  {
    "name": "Member",
    "base": "User",
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
         },
         "password": false
  }
```

Note the I have set the `password` property to false. It will indicate to the loopback ORM that the password column is not used in the model that is extending User.